# How do I find UITableview scroll difference - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, position, scrollview

How to find the scroll difference of a UITableView.
I need to find the difference of the Tableview content scroll  from the tableview top position in swift

I tried the below code,

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            let contentOffset = tableview.frame.origin.y
            let maximumOffset = (contentOffset - scrollView.contentOffset.y)
            let dif  = maximumOffset
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Contents offset of tableview, itself describe as difference between top of content to current scroll position.

Try this and see:

```
print(tableView.contentOffset)
```

---

For more, see Apple Document - [contentOffset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619404-contentoffset)

**[contentOffset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619404-contentoffset)** : The point at which the origin of the content view is offset from the origin of the scroll view.

---

Also look at this refernce:

- [Understanding of Content Offset](https://fizzbuzzer.com/understanding-the-contentoffset-and-contentinset-properties-of-the-uiscrollview-class/)

Answer (score 2):

A `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so it **has** a contentOffset property.

When you're learning about a class, remember to check it's parent class. Sometimes the properties/methods you're looking for are in the parent. (I'm as guilty of forgetting to check the interface of parent classes as anybody.)